# What to do when Euler Lagrange Equation is highly nonlinear ode

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, suppose there is a curve on X-Y plane $y(x)$ defined on $x\in [-a,a]$ satisfying:

1. $y(x)\geqslant 0$;
2. $y(-a)=y(a)=0.$

Rotate $y(x)$ along x-axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and get a solid revolution.

Minimize surface area $A=\int_{-a}^{a}2\pi y\sqrt{1+(y')^2}\mathrm{d}x$, given fixed volume $V=\int_{-a}^{a}\pi y^2\mathrm{d}x=C$, for some constant $C$.

By standard variational method and Lagrange multiplier, ($\lambda$ is Lagrange constant), we get the Euler Lagrange equation, which is nonlinear.
$$\frac{1}{(1+(y')^2)^{1/2}}+\lambda y = \frac{yy''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}}$$

My question is how to do with this nonlinear equations. Is there any way to get the minimal $A$ without solving $y$ explicitly?